# Is it appropriate to add a link to an Area 51 proposal in a tag-wiki?

Tags: support, tag-wiki

There is this tag wiki:

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/octobercms/info

And an Area 51 proposal

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/97119/octobercms

Would it be okay to mention the Area 51 proposal in the tag wiki? If so, in which wording?

As to the why: I'd like to have more exposure of this (IMHO awesome CMS) under 200+ ranking users, and users who use the tag can see there is the initiative for the OctoberCMS Stack Exchange site and hopefully support it so we will have a nice userbase when it goes live.

In the Magento wiki there was the mention of the Magento Stack Exchange proposal:
*https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3609619/11*

But I'm not sure on the consensus if this is an accepted practice.

Comment: You mean in order to get people who use the tag to go over and maybe commit to the proposal?

Comment: yes and to add a bit of exposure to the proposal for people who are intersted/made curious by the tag, and gain more support from people who have more than 200 rep on a stack exchange site.

Comment: I personally think this is a great idea. It makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Well, I went ahead and made the edit :-) http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15434170

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let me preface this by saying that I don't know what the consensus is or if there even is one.

I personally think this is a good idea. It seems like one of the best and most subtle ways of letting users who are really interested in the tag - and **only those** users - know about this proposal without being too *"in your face"* about it. These users are exactly the people you want to reach with the proposal, as they would probably be the only ones who care enough about the framework to commit to the proposal as well.

Tag wikis are supposed to contain information that is especially helpful to the community and I believe this would fit in quite well in a "links" section of the wiki. I can actually not think of a downside to including a link to an area51 proposal for people who are interested in it. If someone doesn't care then it still won't do any harm.

Comment: Except for the fact that on average no one reads the tag wikis

Comment: @TinyGiant and the people that do are probably super interested in the tag.  So it's still a good idea !